# HTTPS call from angular app to c# controller

Tags: angular, https

I am making HTTPS request from angular app to c# controller.

e.g
My environment.ts looks like this:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  apiUrl: 'https://ourlady:4000'
};
```

The extract of code that makes the call (AccountService) looks like below:

```
const baseUrl = `${environment.apiUrl}/accounts`;
refreshToken(account: Account) {
        return this.http.post(`${baseUrl}/refresh-token`, account);
    }
```

I have defined `ourlady` domain in the host file like this:

```
49.187.112.232  ourlady
```

I am getting an error in the browser:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID :4000/accounts/refresh-token:1
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your server to use a valid SSL certificate. This will ensure that your HTTPS requests are encrypted and secure.

Comment: I have configured valid certificate in browser, I thought that was good enough.

Comment: My server is c# `BaseController` type controller. How do I do that?